# Run tensorflow with one graph in multi process

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, ensemble-learning

I've trying to train a classifier with 5 ensemble networks. I decided to train them with different batch, so I want to create multi-processes to save my time.

Here is my algorithm design:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import tensorflow as tf

# create() function returns 5 optimizer for 5 network, i.e. len(opt_list) = 5
opt_list = create()

def sub_process(sess, opt, feed_batch):
    sess.run(opt, feed_dict=feed_batch)

batch_list = []
for i in range(5):
    batch = generate_batch(batch_size=100)
    batch_list.append(batch)

for i in range(5):
    p = mp.Process(target=sub_process, args=(sess, opt_list[i], batch_list[i]))
    p.start()

for i in range(5):
    p.join()
```

First, I build the graph and deploy each network on 5 different devices (I have 5 GPU in total).

Then, I draw samples from the dataset (For example, if I want to feed 100 images to one network then I will generate 500 samples)

Next, I create 5 processes using python3 package multiprocessing. And each process runs a sub_process function given parameters input.

However, when I run the code, I get the following error

```
2018-08-14 18:13:56.776853: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.776940: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.776978: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.777004: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.830762: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.831239: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.831262: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.831285: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:56.902612: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:82] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2018-08-14 18:13:57.654653: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1227] failed to enqueue async memcpy from host to device: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED; GPU dst: 0x1085d87f000; host src: 0x1083783f700; size: 4=0x4
2018-08-14 18:13:57.660200: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1227] failed to enqueue async memcpy from host to device: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED; GPU dst: 0x1085d87f000; host src: 0x1083783f700; size: 4=0x4
2018-08-14 18:13:57.758658: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1227] failed to enqueue async memcpy from host to device: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED; GPU dst: 0x1085d87f000; host src: 0x1083783f700; size: 4=0x4
2018-08-14 18:13:57.808281: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1227] failed to enqueue async memcpy from host to device: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED; GPU dst: 0x1085d87f000; host src: 0x1083783f700; size: 4=0x4
```

Could anyone tell me why there is such an error? What should change in my code to get what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest taking a look at [tf.contrib.distribute](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/distribute), which has a nice API for getting good performance out of multiple GPUs.